# Problem with addactiolistener codename one

Tags: codenameone

When I use this code:

```
`TextField teno=new TextField();
    teno.setHint("Input name");
    Label l=new Label("")
    teno.addActionListener(click->{

        la.setText(teno.getText());
    });
`
```

I get an unexpected behavior because I have to press enter and click twice on the TextField for the entered name to appear in the label

an application that use TextField and Label; in Label would appear the name writen in TextField

Comment: In which platform? The simulator? Device? An action listener only fires when a text field loses focus or a user presses enter. If you want to track every change you can use data change listener.

Comment: In simulator of Eclipse windows 11

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the action listener not firing. It's the UI not refreshing. Change the code to:

```
TextField teno=new TextField();
teno.setHint("Input name");
Label l=new Label("")
teno.addActionListener(click->{
    la.setText(teno.getText());
    l.getParent().revalidate();
});
```

Normally a label will repaint on change but since a zero length label is completely hidden the repaint won't change much. You need to reflow the UI.